# How to write this mathematical formula in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, math, visual-c++, logarithm

I have a simple formula and I want to use it in C++ application.
Not sure how to rewrite in C++.

[image]

Comment: so why the c tag, c++ is different from c. ok please remove the c tag

Comment: where is the integral in this? (btw. you usually approach integrals by discretizing & summing).

Comment: We do people answer him? He didn't put any snippet of his own, he clearly wants someone to do it for him

Comment: @user3104201         If you can not answer please zip up.

Comment: If you can not answer please zip up .@user3104201

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
logn(5, abs((a*b - d*c) / (tan(c) + sin(d))))
```

where `logn` is:

```
double logn(double base, double x) {
    return log(x) / log(base);
}
```

and the header `cmath` is included for the other functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,  be careful with libs, namespaces, and radian arguments

```
z = a*b - d*c; 
s = tan(c) + sin(d);
num = abs(z/s);
log(num)/log(5);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/